# An error occurred when filtering products: Filter field SBQQ__ProductFamily__c does not exist on object Product2

Tags: cpq, product, lookup-filter

--New to Salesforce.
I have created a Product Rule with Type "Filter". In Product Action -> Filter Information , the Filter Field is Product Family. On selecting the Product in Quote , I am getting below error -

An error occurred when filtering products: Filter field SBQQ__ProductFamily__c does not exist on object Product2.

Any advice will be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on above error message

A workaround is to create a Product Family formula field on the Product Option and on Product2 objects and filter on this new field instead.